# Markov inequality proof step

Tags: probability, inequality

Hej,

I am studying a proof for the Markov inequality, and there is a certain step, which I don't understand:

$\mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbb{I}_A) \ge \mathbb{E}(a \mu \mathbb{I_A})$

where $\mathbb{I}_A$ is the indicator function, $\mu = \mathbb{E}(X)$ and $A = [X \ge a \cdot \mathbb{E}(X)]$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is $\Bbb X$?

Comment: I downvoted for the following reasons: 1. as $\Bbb X$ is not defined, the problem is unclear; 2. There is no attempt shown.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typing mistake.
I just have in the proof the following inequalities:
$\mu = \mathbb{E}(X) \ge \mathbb{E}(X \cdot \mathbb{I}_A) \ge \mathbb{E}(a \cdot \mu \cdot \mathbb{I}_A) = a \mu \mathbb{P}[X \ge a \cdot \mu]$, which proofs the Markov inequality. But the step above is unclear. Why is this inequality correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use the pointwise inequality $X\mathbf 1_A\geqslant Y$ with $Y=a\mathbb E(X)\,\mathbf 1_A$. Deduce that $\mathbb E(X\mathbf 1_A)\geqslant\mathbb E(Y)$ and note that $\mathbb E(Y)=a\mathbb E(X)\mathbb P(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$X\mathbb I_A\geqslant aE(X)\mathbb I_A= a\mu \mathbb I_A,$$
because either we are in $A$ and it's by definition, or we aren't and we have equality. Now integrate on both sides.

Comment: why is per definition $X \ge E(X)$?

Comment: That's not what I said. I mean the equality when we have the characteristic function of $A$ on both sides.